# Setting background's opacity without affecting colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to combine palettes I've made : [this one](http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&image_url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnolojesus.org%2Fimgs%2Fbeach.jpg&commit=Go%20Lavish),
that generated a .css and .less

I want to keep the colors but I still need some elements' backgrounds to go transparent, so I made a main.css to add transparency with :

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Yet the problem now is that it changes the color define in the generated .css /.less

So I tried to set only the opacity

```
opacity: 0.5
```

Now it's the text that is affected.

How can I set only the opacity of the background without affecting the color & text ?

Comment: have you tried using rgba for background?

Comment: Yes, and rgba is good for setting opacity, but it also changes the color.

Comment: I think the only css solution you have is to set the desired color as `rgba`.

Answer (score 0):

When changing something's opacity (making it more transparent), you'll automatically change it's color and make it appear brighter. A workaround would be selecting the color in photoshop or something similar, change the layer's opacity and after this adjust the color so that you have the wanted color.